# Sharepoint 2010 Meeting Room Reservation Calendar

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I am looking for SharePoint 2010 Meeting room Reservation Calendar or something similar to it. There are lot of stuff but I am looking specifically with SP2010.

I really appreciate your response.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also have a look at this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v8_3_iLH3EY&context=C3c2aa69ADOEgsToPDskLgWsdtFXkX7Sv3AEzV5fbM

Answer (score 3):

Out of the box, using [group calendar](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/enable-reservation-of-resources-in-a-calendar-HA101810595.aspx).

3rd party product [Room Manager](http://www.roommanager.com/SitePages/Home.aspx) is at least one, based on quick search.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nf9XvEQ2au4&hd=1
The video is about SharePoint 2013, SharePoint 2010 version is the same.

Answer (score 0):

just found another solution for meeting room reservation http://www.sharepointsapiens.com/blog/meeting-room-reservation-sharepoint-calendar/

If you schedule a meeting in the SharePoint calendar and select one of the meeting rooms or any equipment, a meeting request will be send to the associated Exchange mailbox.

If the resource mailbox is configured correctly and the room or the equipment is free, it will be booked automatically and send an acceptance back to the SharePoint calendar. If it is already booked, it will decline the meeting request. The reply status is visible directly in the SharePoint event.

Comment: Please add more details. The links might get broken in future.