# Room Finder or Room Search in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: profile-sync, resources, exchange

I would like to do two things with meeting rooms in SharePoint 2010:

- Search them (scope to resources only)
- Book them (Add them as an option to avaliable/busy in a SharePoint calendar)

I have tried searching but haven't found anything specific enough to my request.

**Setup/Sync**

We have them setup in Exchange right now, and have the associated Active Directory account, but I am unsure how to 'separate' these from normal people profiles when Profile Sync pulls them over to SharePoint.

**Search**

I also would like to setup a page that will perform a search for only room information.  Is there a way to scope this search to only show items that are resources (basically rooms, but projectors and other things would appear here too).

**Booking Calendar**

Is there a way to pull up a list of only rooms/resources when attempting to book in a SharePoint calendar?  Will I need a list populated with rooms or is there some other method to do this?

Thanks very much for any links and direction you can give me!

~~Kolten

Comment: Possible duplicate question http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/30056/sharepoint-2010-meeting-room-reservation-calendar

Comment: No that link does not describe at all what I am looking for, sorry.  I am looking to utilize our "resources" in Active Directory and implement them into a SharePoint Calendar, not a simple 3rd party solution that uses Lists to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution (3rd party developer) :   http://www.eastbanctech.com/conference-rooms-reservation-solution-for-sharepoint-integrating-sharepoint-with-exchange/

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)